# Eclipse RCP doesnt find org.eclipse.ui

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I try to create a PlugIn Project in eclipse it keeps telling me, that it cant find org.eclipse.ui so everythings full of errors. How can I fix that?

BigTeddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your plugin project plugin.xml file, click on dependencies tab and add org.eclipse.ui  to the 'Required Plug-ins'.